# Cannot open OleDbConnection in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, oledbconnection

When trying to read data from mdb using backgroundworker I get an error

> The program '[3768] BackgroundWorkerExample.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

without any other information or exception and I'm not able to catch it. Here is my code, without BGW it works fine. Do I miss something?

```
namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{
public class TestClass
{
    BackgroundWorker _Worker;

    public TestClass()
    {
        InitializeWorker();
    }

    public void InitializeWorker()
    {
        _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        _Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(WorkerDoWork);
        _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerRunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Work completed!");
    }

    private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable data = GetDataTable();
        PrintResults(data);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\students.mdb;";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open(); // crashes here!

                    DataTable res = new DataTable();

                    string query = "SELECT * FROM students";

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                    adapter.Fill(res);

                    return res;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // never reaches this part
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void PrintResults(DataTable data)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(row[i] + "   ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it is throwing an exception?  The 'error' you posted is simply the thread exiting, having completed its work.

Comment: You say that it crashes on the connection.Open. How do you know it?

Comment: Are you running this in a console application? It looks like you are. As you've started the load on a background thread, there is nothing for the application to wait around for, and so the application exits before your background worker completes.

Comment: Oh my god, I am so stupid!!! Of course I have to wait in my calling app till bdw ends its work. Sorry! Thanks, dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not giving enough time for the `BackGroundWorker` to execute.A quick fix would be to check if BackGroundWorker is busy.If it's busy you can make your `Main thread` to wait for sometime so the background worker can complete its job.

The message that you are seeing is not an error, but just an indication that the threads have closed down(`primary and the background worker thread`)

```
public void Run()
{
    _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

     while (_Worker.IsBusy){

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
}
```